# Reading Custom Settings in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, customsetting

I'm creating a page to display to users when we are having periodic maintenance and I want to use custom settings to determine if we're "in maintenance mode". I've created a `Maintenance_Splash_Settings__c` object in Salesforce with the following:

- `InMaintenanceMode__c` Checkbox for yes/no to "in maintenance mode"
- `MaintenanceSplashStartDate__c` Datetime for the start of "in maintenance mode"
- `MaintenanceSplashEndDate__c` Datetime for the end of "in maintenance mode"

My Apex class:

```
public with sharing class MaintenanceSplashController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Maintenance_Splash_Settings__c getMaintenanceSplashSettings() {
        return Maintenance_Splash_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults(); 
    }
}
```

My Lightning component references this controller: `<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="MaintenanceSplashController"`.

My Lightning component helper.js is calling the function to load settings:

```
loadMaintenanceSplashSettings: function(component, event, helper) {           
    let getSettingsAction = component.get("c.getMaintenanceSplashSettings");

    getSettingsAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (component.isValid() && response !== null && response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.maintenanceSplashSettings", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log("Maintenance splash settings loaded");
        } else {
            console.log("Maintenance splash settings failed to load");
        }
    });

    console.log("loading Maintenance splash settings");
    $A.enqueueAction(getSettingsAction);

    let inMaintenanceMode = getSettingsAction.InMaintenanceMode__c;
    let startDate = getSettingsAction.MaintenanceSplashStartDate__c;
    let endDate = getSettingsAction.MaintenanceSplashEndDate__c;

    console.log("Is in maintenance mode? " + inMaintenanceMode);
    console.log("start date: " + startDate);
    console.log("end date: " + endDate);
},
```

The values for `inMaintenanceMode`, `startDate`, and `endDate` are all coming back as undefined. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

**UNDERSTANDING**

I think there is a gap in understanding here. Lets understand each line of code in `loadMaintenanceSplashSettings`:

```
let getSettingsAction = component.get("c.getMaintenanceSplashSettings");
```

This is getting the definition of apex method in javascript.

```
getSettingsAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    // callback code
});
```

`callback code` is run after you get back the response

```
$A.enqueueAction(getSettingsAction);
```

Enqueues the action to be sent to apex server while the current javascript transaction is being carried out.

```
let inMaintenanceMode = getSettingsAction.InMaintenanceMode__c;
let startDate = getSettingsAction.MaintenanceSplashStartDate__c;
let endDate = getSettingsAction.MaintenanceSplashEndDate__c;
```

Now, here is the interesting part, (you should have guessed already) these lines are run even before you get the response from server. Also `getSettingsAction` is just action name but you are actually storing the response in `maintenanceSplashSettings` and so the logs after this is showing undefined.

**SOLUTION**

Just use below JS method:

```
loadMaintenanceSplashSettings: function(component, event, helper) {           
    let getSettingsAction = component.get("c.getMaintenanceSplashSettings");

    getSettingsAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (component.isValid() && response !== null && response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.maintenanceSplashSettings", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log("Maintenance splash settings loaded");
        } else {
            console.log("Maintenance splash settings failed to load");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(getSettingsAction);
},
```

Now get the values in component as below:

```
InMaintenanceMode__c - {!v.maintenanceSplashSettings.InMaintenanceMode__c}
MaintenanceSplashStartDate__c  - {!v.maintenanceSplashSettings.MaintenanceSplashStartDate__c}
MaintenanceSplashEndDate__c  - {!v.maintenanceSplashSettings.MaintenanceSplashEndDate__c }

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.maintenanceSplashSettings.InMaintenanceMode__c}">
    show something when in maintenance mode
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        show actual content when not in maintenance
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

And dont forget to declare the attribute in component:

```
<aura:attribute name="maintenanceSplashSettings" type="Map" default="{}" />
```